# Mathematica PiecewiseExpand and plots

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, bspline

When I'm using Mathematica command:

"Plot[BSplineBasis[3, x], {x, 0, 1}]"

then I get a nice function plot. However, when I use:

"Plot[PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis[3, x]], {x, 0, 1}]"

then the plot has 2 breaks in it, one larger around x=0.26 and one smaller around x=0.77. In my knowledge I should get the same plot in both cases because the curves are equal, only their representation (way of calculating) are different. Can anyone explain the breaks on the second plot. Thank you.

[First plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWMdH.png)
[Second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdxPa.png)

Regards/Mikael

Comment: See Dr.B's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19878/9490) - you just need to add the option `Exclusions -> None` to the `Plot` command.